# How to delete folders that are older than some days using camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I wanted to poll a directory and delete the files and folders that are older than a specified time. I wrote the following code :-

```
            from("file:input?filterFile=${date:file:yyyyMMddHHmm} <= ${date:now-240h:yyyyMMddHHmm}&delay=60000&delete=true")
            .log("The headers are ${headers}");
```

It works fine for files and the old files are deleted but this does not work on folders. Can anyone suggest a way to make it work on folders also?

Comment: Anyone can also suggest any different way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: Camel doesn't work with the directories, You have to code the logic yourself to delete directories. https://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/File-consumer-with-recursive-true-Delete-subfolder-td478505.html

Comment: @UmaisGillani thank you. I found that by setting recursive = true it is performing the delete operation on the files in the sub folders also , but the empty folders still remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a processor to write your logic in java as Apache camel doesn't work on directories, you can try something like below.

```
from("timer://myTimer?period=2000")
.process(new Processor() {

    public void process(Exchange exchange)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Deleting Directories");
        File directory = new File("D:\\basedirectory");
        removeDirectory(1, directory);
    }

    public void removeDirectory(int daysBack, File directory) {
        if(directory.exists()){
            final File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();          
            final long purgeTime = 
                System.currentTimeMillis() - (daysBack * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            for(File listFile : listFiles) {
                if(listFile.lastModified() < purgeTime) {
                    System.out.println(listFile.getName() + " - deleted");
                    listFile.delete();
                }
            }
        } 
    }
})
.end();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer , this was something I was looking for. Can you help me understand what setBody() and simple("files deleted") will do ?

Comment: And also what is the need to send something to "stream:out"?

Comment: Actually that's for the log print on console while running in IDE just for the test, you can remove. You just need from().process().end() that would do the work and if you need logs your can use systemouts in process()

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For only for sub directories you can use you can try http://www.instanceofjava.com/2018/02/java-8-delete-folder-and-subfolders.html or something similar to

```
File directory = new File(dirWay);
if(directory.exists()){

File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();           
long purgeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - (daysBack * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

for(File listFile : listFiles) {
    if(listFile.lastModified() < purgeTime) {
      FileUtils.forceDelete(new File(listFile.getPath())); // or your way to delete
    }
  }
}
```

public static void forceDelete(File file)
                        throws IOException

Deletes a file. If file is a directory, delete it and all sub-directories. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#forceDelete(java.io.File)

Comment: create custom functionality, class etc

Comment: or https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.camel.util.FileUtil/deleteFile

Answer (score 1):

Draft decision, as example,java decision

```
File directory = new File(dirWay);
if(directory.exists()){

File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();           
long purgeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - (daysBack * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);// how old

int  i = listFiles.length //for checking if directory is empty // you can use your logic for checking directory is empty or not

for(File listFile : listFiles) {
    if(listFile.lastModified() < purgeTime) {
      if(listFile.delete()) {
        i--;  //for checking if directory is empty // you can use your logic for checking directory is empty or not   
      }

    }
  }
}

if (i == 0) { // check if directory empty delete it. Because of all files older than 10yers then directory older too. // you can use your logic for checking directory is empty or not
  FileUtils.forceDelete(new File(dirWay));
}
```

public static void forceDelete(File file)
                        throws IOException

Deletes a file. If file is a directory, delete it and all sub-directories. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#forceDelete(java.io.File)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,  I understood what you are trying to say. I had one doubt where exactly should I add this part of the code in my camel code above. Also will this poll the directory at regular intervals as in my case new files will keep adding the parent directory , so I don't want to delete the parent directory , I only want to perform the delete operations on sub directories.

Comment: For only for sub directories you can use you can try http://www.instanceofjava.com/2018/02/java-8-delete-folder-and-subfolders.html or

Comment: create custom functionality, class etc

Comment: or https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.camel.util.FileUtil/deleteFile